# Selecting corresponding nth element to show but hide all siblings

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list, with each list item corresponding to a block of text. When I click on a list item, I'd like the corresponding block of text to show, while hiding all other siblings. I'd like this to work with any arbitrary number of list items. The list and block of text always correspond 1 to 1. Basically, clicking on topic 1 should show block of text 1, while hiding others, and clicking topic 2 should show block of text 2 and hide others, so on. I couldn't get the code to work below. Any suggestions?

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".topics li").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
        $(this).attr("class","active");
        var index = $(".topics li").index(this);

        $("div.chatContent").eq(index).show(150);
        $("div.chatContent").eq(index).siblings.hide(150);
    });
});
```

The HTML snippet is:

```
                    <div class="topics">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Topic 1</li>
                            <li>Topic 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="chatContent">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Block of text 1 </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                     <div class="chatContent">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Block of text 2 </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A syntax error found,

```
$("div.chatContent").eq(index).siblings().hide(150);
//--------------------------------------^  missing brackets here..
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pHdSy/)

Corrected Code:

```
$("div.chatContent").hide();

$(".topics li").click(function () {
    $('.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("div.chatContent").hide(150).eq($(this).index()).show(150);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcgHz/2/)

- `.siblings()` and not `.siblings`
- And just `.siblings()` will  hide **All the siblings** - including the `<ul>` and `<li>`. So you need to use `.siblings('.chatContent')`.
- Also initially, you need to hide `.chatContent`

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.chatContent').hide();
    $(".topics li").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
        $(this).attr("class", "active");
        var index = $(".topics li").index(this);

        $("div.chatContent").eq(index).show(150).siblings('.chatContent').hide(150);
    });
});
```